# Magento: How to set VAT attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, magento

i am new to this magento world and stuck in a problem. i need to create a attribute rule which can add 20% in all prices by default. in fact i created 1 rule with name "standard VAT" in sales> Tax> Manage Tax rule.

but by default magento is using "none" in Product > Price > Tax Class. how can we make magento use tax attribute "Standard VAT" by default?

i know one way is by selecting all products and editing attribute, but that is not the solution, if we go this route we have to apply edit it every minute. as our listing updates every 30 minute.

we need a 1 time solution please, all our newly add products and existing products can auto use that attribute.

if you know any way we can edit any file in magento please advise us with full file path, code to add and line number.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: i did what ever they recommenced here but this inst the solution for me: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-vat-gst

Answer (score 0):

1. product tax class are applied on product but you need to specify in every product in price section last option *Tax Class*
2. customer tax class apply on customer specify in customer group
3. tax price and zone are specify in manage tax zone and rate